# Universal Window: Binding class data to datagrid

Tags: c#, binding, universal

Code: XAML

```
<GridView x:Name="grid1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="57,336,0,148"  Width="222">
            <Grid Margin="0,2">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="100"></ColumnDefinition>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="100"></ColumnDefinition>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <TextBox Text="{Binding Name}"></TextBlock>
                <TextBox Text="{Binding ID}" Grid.Column="0"></TextBox>
                <TextBox Text="{Binding Age}" Grid.Column="1"></TextBox>
            </Grid>
        </GridView>
```

Code: C#

```
public tstrTable()
{
   this.InitializeComponent();
   grid1.Items.Add(new con90() { Name = "Hello", ID = "Simple", Age = 20 });
}

class con90
{
   public string Name { get; set; }
   public string ID { get; set; }
   public int Age { get; set; }
}
```

Output: con90

Expected output: Addition to gridview1, three items (Name, ID and Age). **How to achieve this?**

OS: Windows 10
Platform: .NETCore (Universal Window)

New to this system & XAML, resources seem somewhat limited on the net with this newer form of applications development.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Addition: Please note that this application is a snippet. The "real thing" uses a far larger con90 class and obtains its information from external resources. This snippet merely shows the error that I cannot seem to over-come.

Comment: what is displaying now? did you bind the datacontex/datasource?

Comment: grid1 displays: "app/con90" instead of data. The code above is all I have, much of the nets content isn't applicable to universal window applications from what I have seen

Comment: can you try such syntax:`<GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Age}"  Header="Age" Width="100"/>` this is wpf and i'm not familiar with uwp yet.

Comment: GridViewColumn does not apply to uwp

Comment: yes i just tried, but there's a lot of tutorials online which defined `ItemTemplate`.

Comment: There's also a wide variety of 'observablecollection' tutorials, which seem very relevant. Any solution to this, or a workaround, would be great.

Comment: yes you should use bindings, instead of adding items.

Comment: How to use binding with grid using the example above?

Answer (score 0):

Update: 
After some sleep, I read back over my post & the comments. 
Quickly, I found this tutorial: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/32813.uwp-data-binding-grid-view-and-list-view-controls.aspx

Perfect! Now I can bind data from a class into my UWP!

Thanks to Lei Yang for providing me with keywords, and prompting me to recollect some myself.